# Why is only one of these almost identical HTML-forms reacting to submit button click?

Tags: laravel, forms, form-submit

I have two almost identical forms. One is meant to edit an item, and the other is meant to create an item. For some reason, the create-form does not react at all to submit button clicks, while the edit/update form works exactly as expected. I can not find any differences between the two that should result in this behavior.

I am as sure as I can be that this has nothing to do with back end. I have monitored network activity, ant the submit button for the create-form does not activate any kind of network activity at all.

Working update form:

```
@extends ('layout')

@section('middle-content')

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="page" class="container">
            <h4>Edit Competition Category</h4>

            <form method="POST" action="/competition-categories/{{$competitionCategory->id}}">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="competition-category-name-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="competition-category-name-input" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ $competitionCategory->name }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="competition-category-abbreviation-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Abbreviation</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="competition-category-abbreviation-input" name="abbreviation" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ $competitionCategory->abbreviation }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Non-responding create-form:

```
@extends ('layout')

@section('middle-content')

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="page" class="container">
            <h4>New Competition Category</h4>

            <form method="POST" action="/competition-categories"></form>
                @csrf

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="competition-category-name-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="competition-category-name-input" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="competition-category-abbreviation-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Abbreviation</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="competition-category-abbreviation-input" name="abbreviation" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: At the non responding form you started the _form_ and ended it in the same line

Comment: Why did you closed </form> tag just after the opening form in the non responding form?? you need to remove additional </form> tag.

Comment: You're right... It's always something stupid. I have two end tags for the form, one in the right place, and one totally wrong.... Thanks!

Comment: @DipakMewada I have no valid excuse. Just made a mistake. I'm using a new IDE, and I'm obviously not quite accustomed to the automatic code generation it provides, and the errors I might end up with, because of it. Thanks for helping me find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line: `<form method="POST" action="/competition-categories"></form>` 
of your non working form, please remove `</form>` you started and closed it that's why.